# Link two Google Accounts

Tags: gmail, google-analytics

I have two Google Accounts.

1. me@gmail.com
2. me@mycompany.com

`me@mycompany.com` is not a Gmail and is not a Google Apps for my domain account. The email `me@mycompany.com` hosted somewhere outside of Google.

But I hate having to switch between the two.  Is there a way to link them, so that when I log on to `me@gmail.com`, I still have access to `me@mycompany.com` services in Google?

Specifically I am looking to solve this problem on Google Analytics (GA). The `me@gmail.com` account on GA shows my personal sites where the `me@mycompany.com` shows my work sites.  I'd like to log on via `me@gmail.com` and see both personal and work sites with the privileges of both accounts

Comment: Can you clarify this:

"My Gmail account on GA shows my personal sites where the me@mycompany.com shows my work sites." ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% positive (Since I use 2 Google Accounts) but I believe you can give access to your Google Analytics site to me@gmail.com even though it was created by me@mycompany.com. I have two Google Accounts, account1@gmail.com and account2@gmail.com. I setup GA for account1 and then later gave access to account2 to view the stats.

Heres a Help Post from Google. [How do I grant other users access to my Analytics reports?](https://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55500&hl=en_US)

But if you wanted to share e-mail as well, you can fwd your mail from me@mycompany.com to me@gmail.com. And with-in GMail you can change the "Sent From" to me@mycompany.com while logged into me@gmail.com

Comment: It seems to me after searching around google, that this is the only solution.  You cannot really link google accounts.  But, for my specific case with GA, giving access to another account is the solution.

Thanks.